# C# How to do this anonymous method injection

Tags: c#, anonymous-methods, anonymous-class

How do I use something like this in C#.

```
 Console.WriteLine("yaya instant");
 Server.registerEvent(new Event(5000) {
    public void doWork() {
        this.stop();
        Console.WriteLine("yaya 5 seconds later");
    }
  });
```

**Event** class and the **doWork()** method is declared inside **Event** class.

Pretty much what is going on is doWork() is abstract method which should get created by the code above.

Whats the proper syntax to do this in C#? is it even possible to do anonymous methods like this?. (The above code is not valid syntax, if someone doesn't understand this question.)

Thank you I appreciate the help.

Comment: You wrote "Event class and the doWork() method is declared inside Event class." How can Event class be declared inside Event class? Is it declared inside itself?

Comment: public abstract void doWork();       inside Event.cs   there is no method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do this. 
You need to create a sub class of Event that accepts an action.

```
public class MyEvent: Event
{
    private Action _action;        

    public MyEvent(int milliseconds, Action action)
        : base(milliseconds)
    {
        _action= action;
    }

    public override void doWork()
    {
        action()
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
Server.registerEvent(new MyEvent(5000, () => 
    {
        this.stop();
        Console.WriteLine("yaya 5 seconds later");
    }));
```

You just need to declare MyEvent once (call it something better), and then you can create instances of it with different actions when you need them.

Comment: Okay but I have to create these events in the middle of a codeflow

Comment: Okay then you need to crate a class that derives from Event that accepts an action.

Comment: Updated answer to do what you want.

Comment: Looks pretty nice, i'll try it out soon.

Comment: Tired this, but how do I call this.stop()..      stop() is a method of Event.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have anonymous classes in C#. Is that what you are asking? But in C# you normally wouldn't implement a class for handling an event anyway.

Comment: What is my other option for crafting event on demand all over my code other then using timer class.

Comment: I don't understand really what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to make events on demand all over classes.. yet keeping a nice design. Without making events in a new class.. but keeping all the logic in the same class file. Ah it's alright I guess i'll try something else.

Comment: I still don't understand your requirement. What is an "event on demand"?

Comment: Ah nothing just trying to keep it pretty looking and creating events when I want too in a simplistic ways to make scripts easily craftable.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of is this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace SO6304593
{    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("yaya instant");

            Thread t1 = new Thread(delegate(object x) { Thread.Sleep((int)x); Console.WriteLine("Hello 1");});
            Thread t2 = new Thread(x => {Thread.Sleep((int)x); Console.WriteLine("Hello 2");});

            t1.Start(5000);
            t2.Start(3000);
            t1.Join();
            t2.Join();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this what you are after? The above are two examples of using anonymous methods in C#: the delegated syntax and the lambda syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Give your event class a property of type Action:

```
public class Event
{
    public Action doWork { get; set; }
}
```

Then use as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine("yaya instant");
Server.registerEvent(new Event(5000) {
    doWork = delegate {
        this.stop();
        Console.WriteLine("yaya 5 seconds later");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the method injection add an Action arg in the constructor to Event then you could do it like this;

```
Console.WriteLine("yaya instant");
Server.registerEvent(
    new Event(5000, () {
        stop();
        Console.WriteLine("yaya 5 seconds later");
        )
    );

Event::Event(int time, Action action){...}
```